# how to know if awk command printed something without spoiling original output

Tags: bash, gawk, awk

I'm trying to use AWK command, it's printing for me very well and what exact way I want

My question is, how can I know from script if the awk command I used has printed something without spoiling and change the way it prints ?

commands I used:
`gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/word1|word2/' input_file.log`

I tried:

`status=gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/word1|word2/' input_file.log`

```
if [ -z $status]
then
    //status is empty or null, means nothing printed in awk command
    echo "nothing"
else
    //printed something in awk command
    echo $status
```

the issue is that `echo $status` prints in sequence all the lines, without the "new lines" between the lines

how can print the original prints from awk without spoiling it?

example:
input file:

```
line 0 no words in here

line 1 starting
line 1 word1

line 2 no words here as well

line 3 starting
line 3 word2
line 3 end

line 4 nothing
line 5 nothing
```

command:
`gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/word1|word2/' input_file.log`

expected output:

```
line 1 starting
line 1 word1

line 3 starting
line 3 word2
line 3 end
```

if I use:
`stat=$(gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/word1|word2/' input_file.log)`
`echo $stat`

I get as output:

```
line 1 starting line 1 word1 line 3 starting line 3 word2 line 3 end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) If you set `RS=""` instead of `RS="\n\n"` your script will work the same but not be gawk-specific, 2) without word boundaries you'll match on `foobar` when looking for `foo`, 3) shell comments start with `#`, not `//`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not fully sure as you haven't shown any sample Input_file or expected output, so could you please try using `echo "$status"`.

**EDIT:** As you have edited your post now, so you should change your code to following and it should fly then.

```
status=$(awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"} {s=tolower($0)} s~/word1|word2/' Input_file)
if [[ -z $status ]]
then
    echo "nothing"
else
    echo "$status"
fi
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you, make sure you are making those necessary changes which I had mentioned in my post(fixed few syntax issues in your code) too. Let me know if any queries on same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exit` code for checking whether `awk` has printed something or not

Correct your code

**From**

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n" {s=tolower($0)} s~/word1|word2/' input_file.log
```

**TO**

```
status=$(gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}tolower($0)~/word1|word2/' input_file.log)
```

and (with quotes)

```
echo "$status"
```

> **This happens because** when you quote a parameter (whether that
>   parameter is passed to `echo`, `test` or some other command), the value of
>   that parameter is sent as one value to the command. If you don't quote
>   it, the shell does its normal magic of looking for whitespace to
>   determine where each parameter starts and ends.

**To correct existing code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

status=$(gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}tolower($0)~/word1|word2/' input_file.log)
if [  -z "$status" ]; then
       echo "looks like nothing matched and so nothing printed"
else
       echo "awk matched regex and printed something"
fi
```

**Here is code for checking awk has printed something or not using exit code :**

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}f=(tolower($0)~/word1|word2/){e=1}f; END{exit !e}' input_file.log

# check exit code 
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "awk matched regex and printed something"
else
       echo "looks like nothing matched and so nothing printed"
fi
```

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}f=(tolower($0)~/word1|word2/){e=1}f; END{exit !e}' "$1"
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "awk matched regex and printed something"
else
       echo "looks like nothing matched and so nothing printed"
fi
```

**sample files for testing**

```
$ echo 'word1' >file1

$ echo 'nothing' >file2
```

**Contents of files**

```
$ cat file1
word1

$ cat file2
nothing
```

**Execution with first file**

```
$ bash test.sh file1
word1

awk matched regex and printed something
```

**Execution with second file**

```
$ bash test.sh file2
looks like nothing matched and so nothing printed
```

Comment: Thanks! worked with quotes, and thanks for explaining the quotes thing, did not know that before (Y)